# SQl игнорирование спец символов

Tags: sql-server

День добрый

У меня такая проблема что имеется какойто текст который генерируется не мной и в котором может быть написано всё что угодно. В самом тексе следовательно может находиться и одинарные кавычки которые портят весть запрос. Как сделать так чтобы MS SQL игнорировал ковычки в нутри текста который я пытаюсь занести?

```
INSERT INTO eventCollector.dbo.events (text) VALUES ('Это 'тескт' который генерируется')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно хранить содержимое текста примерно в том самом виде в котором вы его получили, то [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186862.aspx) одинарные кавычки на двойные (а так же все другие запрещенные символы - мало ли что придет к вам в качестве аргумента) но в таком случае вам надо помнить весь набор замененных символов и восстанавливать исходный текст кучей обратных Replace-ов

Если же вы просто храните текст и не собираетесь производить по нему поиск Like-ом в последствии, то предпочтительнее будет [кодировать в Base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s70ad5f6.aspx) и не парится о символах которые поменяли. Естественно полученная строка не будет содержать в себе левых символов и прекрасно декодируется в исходный текст обратной функцией

Comment: Экранировку отменили в ms sql?)